How to fill a buffer in an struct and display it at the same time?
I'm having trouble with the lifetime of a buffer.
I want my main program to be responsible to fill a struct and a buffer.
My struct fills the buffer in an "infinite" loop.
For each iteration of the loop, I want to print the buffer content. Something like this:
fn main() {
    let mut buffer = [0.0; 1024];
    let mut obj = MyObject::new(&mut buffer);
    loop {
        obj.fill_buffer();
        for i in 0..1024 {
            println!("Sample {}: {}", i, buffer[i]);
        }
    }
}

My struct looks like this:
struct MyObject<'a> {
    a_value: f64,
    buffer: &'a mut [f64],
}

impl<'a> MyObject<'a> {
    fn new(buffer: &'a mut [f64]) -> MyObject<'a> {
        MyObject { a_value: 1.0, buffer: buffer }
    }

    fn fill_buffer(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..self.buffer.len() {
            self.buffer[i] = 1.0;
        }
    }
}

From the error messages "cannot borrow buffer as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable" and things like this which depends on my tests and rust documentation, I understand that the problem comes from that I display buffer just after the call fill_buffer.
fill_buffer uses a reference and it seems to pose a problem to rust to call it and to get value just after in the same scope.
How can I have an infinite loop that calls fill_buffer on the struct and displays it just after? I want main to be responsible for creating the buffer. And I want the buffer to be in the struct, not passed as parameter to fill_buffer.
EDIT Here is the code corrected with accepted answer of kmdreko:
struct MyObject<'a> {
    a_value: i64,
    buffer: &'a mut [f64],
}

impl<'a> MyObject<'a> {
    fn new(buffer: &'a mut [f64]) -> MyObject<'a> {
        MyObject { a_value: 0, buffer: buffer }
    }

    fn fill_buffer(&mut self) -> &[f64] {
        for i in 0..self.buffer.len() {
            self.buffer[i] = i as f64 * self.a_value as f64;
        }

        self.buffer
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = [0.0; 8];
    let mut obj = MyObject::new(&mut buffer);
    for i in 1..9 {
        obj.a_value = i;
        let buffer = obj.fill_buffer();
        for j in 0..8 {
            println!("Loop {}: subloop: {}: sample {}", i, j, buffer[j]);
        }
    }
}


You have given exclusive access of buffer to obj by holding a mutable reference, so main() can't access buffer while obj has it.
I see two options:

re-create obj on each iteration of the loop, so it may be destroyed (releasing its exclusive access) before printing at the end, or

borrow the buffer back:
impl<'a> MyObject<'a> {
    fn buffer(&self) -> &[f64] {
        self.buffer
    }
}




Great thank you, it works great !
So, the action of returning the reference and affecting to another variable "tells" the compiler than the reference is not more owned by the struct, something like this ?

Not quite, obj still has the exclusive reference so buffer can't be used, but it can loan out more references based on it.

@kmdreko can i ask a follow up on the same question? Since buffer is stack allocated fixed sized array and still exists till the end of the main function scope, allowing read-only access to buffer for printing isn't memory unsafe, is this the limitation of rust ? or am i understanding it completely wrong.

You won't get out-of-bound reads or use-after-frees if that's what you mean. You could still have data-races though (if threads are Incorporated) and on top of that Rust assumes strong guarantees about the immutability of shared references and the exclusively of mutable references which allow optimizations that could be incorrect if those guarantees are broken. Not necessarily in the simple example you have, but the rules are generalized.

thanks @kmdreko, whenever rust gives me compilation error, I just like to wonder what could've gone wrong if the compiler just compiled without error. I thought about use-after-free case only, in fact I didn't even thought about multi-threaded condition. Thanks again.
